# How do I use a U2F key to log into google account in firefox on android

Tags: firefox-for-android, fido-u2f

My u2f key is already setup and working as the second factor on my google account, and I've used it many times, including using it with this tablet via usb.

I now want to log into my google account in the firefox browser on my galaxy tab a. When I try, I only get the option to enter a backup code.

I checked about:config and security.webauth.u2f is set to true.
Security.webauth.webauthn is true.
Security.webauth.webauthn_enable_usbtoken is true.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a complete answer, but Google has apparently added some behavior at this point: There's now a URL (https://g.co/sc) given when you get to needing the second factor that you can use in another device to get a one-time use code.

I was able to switch to chrome on the same phone and use that URL. Chrome then prompted me for my FIDO key, which worked fine and I was able to login to firefox.

In no way is this ideal, but at least it's a workaround.